# Issue with if statement in react componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log(
      "more info needeed status:",
      this.props.userDetails.moreInfoNeeded
    ); //true
    console.log(
      "Address status:",
      this.props.userDetails.addressHistory.length
    ); // 0
    if (
      this.props.userDetails.moreInfoNeeded === true &&
      this.props.userDetails.addressHistory.length === 0
    ) {
      console.log("both");
      // this.setState({ renderAddressAndUserDetails: true });
    } else if (
      this.props.userDetails.moreInfoNeeded === false &&
      this.props.userDetails.addressHistory.length === 0
    ) {
      console.log("address");
      // this.setState({ addressStatus: true });
    } else if (
      this.props.userDetails.moreInfoNeeded === true &&
      this.props.userDetails.addressHistory.length !== 0
    ) {
      console.log("user");
      // this.setState({ userDetailsStatus: true });
    }
    console.log(
      "more info needeed status 2:",
      this.props.userDetails.moreInfoNeeded
    );
    console.log(
      "Address status 1:",
      this.props.userDetails.addressHistory.length
    );
  };
```

`this.props.userDetails.moreInfoNeeded` and `this.props.userDetails.addressHistory.length` are `true` and `0` respectively on component did mount, I would expect the first if statement to be true but for some reason all if statements don't work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please check the type of the props values ..  maybe the moreInfoNeeded be string instead of boolean

Answer (score 0):

Strict equality failing hints at type mismatches. Nevertheless it seems better to write

```
this.props.userDetails.moreInfoNeeded &&
  this.props.userDetails.addressHistory.length == 0
```

As `=== false` (use *not* `!`) and `=== true` are remunched conditions.